# How can I restrict specific parameters in payload from API Gateway to AWS Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have to send a request body (payload) from API Gateway to AWS Lambda. In that payload, I only need to send:

```
{
    "path":"aaa"
    "action":"xyz"
}
```

If someone passes any other parameter in the payload, it should not accept the payload and show an error message. Could somebody please help me with the logic?

Answer (score 1):

For AWS API Gateway you can implement request validation using an OpenAPI template. The extension should work for both Rest and Http APIs.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-request-validation.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-request-validator.html

For even more flexibility you could implement a Lambda authorizer which evaluates the body, but of course this leads to more costs as well:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html